# Twitter API JSONP Rate Limit Apigee and Heroku or Authenticate?

Tags: heroku, twitter, jsonp

From what I can tell if I have my app on Heroku and use Apigee, I can increase the unauthenticated rate limit from 150 => 20,000 requests per hour.  Is this the case?  The post below talks about it.

http://hyperballadry.wordpress.io/2011/01/09/increasing-api-limits-on-a-sinatra-twitter-app-with-twitter_oauth-apigee-and-heroku/

However I am doing JSONP calls using AJAX from the client.  Like below:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends/andrew_herrick.json?cursor=-1,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        timeout: 10000
    });
```

What can I do to increase the rate for a user who is on my website hitting the API?  Will just the fact of my site being on Heroku with the Apigee add on handle this?

What if my site wasn't on Heroku, how else could I increase the rate limit?  Would I somehow have to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only thing you need to change.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://twitter.apigee.com/statuses/friends/andrew_herrick.json?cursor=-1,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout: 10000
});
```

Comment: It's a good twitter API proxy site! Where can I find a documentation of http://twitter.apigee.com?